# Distribution of topic partitions by concurrentMessageListenerContainer

Tags: spring-kafka

i'm setting up a   ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer

```
<bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer" id="messageListenerContainer">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="consumerFactory"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="containerProperties"/>
        <property name="concurrency" value="2"/>
    </bean>
```

ConsumerFactory use this config:

```
    <util:map id="consumerConfig" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="#{T(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG}"
               value="${rp.kafka.bootstrap.servers}"/>
        <entry key="#{T(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG}"
               value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer"/>
        <entry key="#{T(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG}"
               value="org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer"/>
        <entry key="#{T(org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer).TRUSTED_PACKAGES}"
               value="*"/>
        <entry key="#{T(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG}"
               value="org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor"/>
        <entry key="#{T(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig).ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG}"
               value="false"/>
    </util:map>
```

and ContainerProperties are

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties" id="containerProperties">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>sendSMS</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="groupId" value="main"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener"/>
        <property name="ackMode" value="RECORD"/>
    </bean>
```

My topic "sendSMS" has 5 partitions on 3-noded cluster with rep factor of 3, so i expect that each KafkaMessageListenerContainer created by Concurrent one (total 2 in that case) will take it's portion of partitions to handle. Hovewer, after an application is started i see in my debugger window that each listener is handling all 5! partitions
https://gyazo.com/183626ff60061b471858f8cc52573353
and message from 4-th partition (its where i have a message that hangs the processing and not being commited after restarts, but its not related to this issue) on the same offset is being delivered 2 times in different threads with different consumers! Why it happens so? Is it a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing enough information. The concurrent container aggregates the assigned partitions for the child `KafkaListenerContainer`s (one for each concurrency).

```
@Override
public Collection<TopicPartition> getAssignedPartitions() {
    return this.containers.stream()
            .map(KafkaMessageListenerContainer::getAssignedPartitions)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You need to show logs for the re-delivery; turn on DEBUG logging for more information.